# Should I flag WordPress questions as off-topic on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, migration, wordpress-se

I understand that the general consensus is that WordPress-specific questions should originate on wordpress.stackexchange.com and only be migrated to SO if they are of more "generic" or "algorithmic".

However, there are lots of **new** questions on Stack Overflow that are WordPress-specific and still left alone on SO, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638424/wordpress-can-i-get-rewrite-rules-for-a-given-path), which is currently also has a bounty, so I'm sure many people saw it.

I personally feel that WordPress-specific questions should be migrated to their specific site, since it will benefit both Stack Overflow and wordpress.stackexchange.com users. However, since I see that these questions are left as-is on SO, I wonder if I should mark them as "off-topic" or not? And if not, why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with you—a question as specific to WP as the one you point to should definitely be migrated.

Generally though (not related to that specific question), before voting to migrate, always  remember the first rule of migration: **Don't migrate crap.** Many incoming WordPress questions are so bad that they don't deserve migration before they have been improved.

Answer (score 2):

Many of the sites have some amount of overlap - this is one such case. It has been said that if a question would be on-topic on either site, then it is valid on either site. Arguably, developing for WordPress (e.g. themes, plugins) is a subset of programming, so coding-related questions would certainly be on-topic on SO.

If a question is *heavily* slanted towards WordPress, then migration may be appropriate. If it's a little more general, like building themes or plugins in a more general sense, than it's certainly fair game here.

Comment: Well such approach makes life considerably harder for WordPress developers. It means they need to duplicate all their searches on two sites, because both are equally authoritative. I frankly don't know what is the value of a separate WordPress site in this case.

Comment: @haimg I don't think you will get around *some* amount of duplication - that's normal. You will have to search two sites for a while but that isn't that hard, and over time, WP.SE will have the more authoritative answers. That said, if a question is *entirely* about an aspect of the WordPress API (like the question you showed) I agree it should be migrated.